# Which Dieharder tests would be most useful?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, random-generation

The wonderful Dieharder suite has lots of different tests available:

```
  -d 0                        Diehard Birthdays Test          Good
  -d 1                           Diehard OPERM5 Test          Good
  -d 2                Diehard 32x32 Binary Rank Test          Good
  -d 3                  Diehard 6x8 Binary Rank Test          Good
  -d 4                        Diehard Bitstream Test          Good
  -d 5                                  Diehard OPSO       Suspect
  -d 6                             Diehard OQSO Test       Suspect
  -d 7                              Diehard DNA Test       Suspect
  -d 8            Diehard Count the 1s (stream) Test          Good
  -d 9              Diehard Count the 1s Test (byte)          Good
  -d 10                     Diehard Parking Lot Test          Good
  -d 11     Diehard Minimum Distance (2d Circle) Test         Good
  -d 12     Diehard 3d Sphere (Minimum Distance) Test         Good
  -d 13                         Diehard Squeeze Test          Good
  -d 14                            Diehard Sums Test    Do Not Use
  -d 15                            Diehard Runs Test          Good
  -d 16                           Diehard Craps Test          Good
  -d 17                 Marsaglia and Tsang GCD Test          Good
  -d 100                            STS Monobit Test          Good
  -d 101                               STS Runs Test          Good
  -d 102               STS Serial Test (Generalized)          Good
  -d 200                   RGB Bit Distribution Test          Good
  -d 201       RGB Generalized Minimum Distance Test          Good
  -d 202                       RGB Permutations Test          Good
  -d 203                         RGB Lagged Sum Test          Good
  -d 204            RGB Kolmogorov-Smirnov Test Test          Good
  -d 205                           Byte Distribution          Good
  -d 206                                     DAB DCT          Good
  -d 207                          DAB Fill Tree Test          Good
  -d 208                        DAB Fill Tree 2 Test          Good
  -d 209                          DAB Monobit 2 Test          Good
```

But running the entire set is really slow. If it wasn't necessary to run them all or time prohibited that, which of the included tests would be most useful/telling to use?

(It's my understanding that each test approaches this difficult problem with its own strategy – you can't ever know for sure how random something is and the more tests the better. In my case, I'm looking for a good approximation of randomness using a handful of the tests.)

Comment: Each test corresponds to a facet of what "randomness" means, so there is not an absolute scale of "usefulness" to rank them.

Comment: Select the tests most relevant for your intended application(s) of the random number generator.

Comment: Thanks, I guess I was hoping there would be a handful of tests that would be a good approximation without having to run the full suite